# How to solve this TabStop style Issue

Tags: c++, c, mfc, window

I know that using isDialogMessage() function we can able to switch the focus from one control to another.
My doubt is

- is it possible to override that the control should focus from first button to third button.
- If possible how to customize WS_TABSTOP property

I also like to know that on what basis the focus is shifted from control to control.

How to set the tabindex property for each control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine which control after which you want to insert the new control in the tab order then use SetWindowPos like this:

SetWindowPos(hNewControl, hOldControl, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);

This changes the z-order of controls which, in turn, establishes the tab order.

Answer (score 6):

The order for tab stop depends on the order in which the controls have been added on the dialog.
You can open the dialog in the resource editor in Visual Studio and press **CTRL+D** to see and modify the tab order.

To modify just press on the number that appears in the top left of the control. The control with the number 1 will be the first control to have focus on your dialog, the order is given by consecutive numbers.
Using this method you can set any tab order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it in mfc. its working ...but how to order the controls focus in win32 application

Comment: Are your dialogs created from a resource or are the controls explicitly created in code?

Comment: the controls are explicitly created in code only.please do some needful for me.

Comment: If you create controls in code the order is set by the creation order. So the first control will create will be the first in the tab order and so on. You can use SetWindowPos after creation and change the z-order to change the tab order.

Comment: can you please provide some sample for this issue?